# What are the differences between the main() function and other user-defined functions in C?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

The `main()` function is known as a user-defined function in C. But how does it differ from other user-defined functions?

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` function is just a regular user-defined function — but it has two special properties:

- In a hosted implementation (the normal type), it is the function called by the start-up code.
- In C99 and later, if execution falls off the end of `main()` without an explicit `return` statement, it is equivalent to `return 0;`.  No other function gets that privileged treatment.

See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for some caveats about the second point.